# Do EA Origin PC downloadable games require a client?

Tags: pc, origin, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I want to buy Need for Speed Most Wanted for PC, and it is [available for $9.99 on Origin.](https://www.origin.com/en-us/store/buy/nfs-most-wanted-2013/pc-download/base-game/standard-edition)

Would I need to install a client to play the game if I buy from there? If yes, how big/bloated/bulky is the client?

Edit: I guess the answer is yes. And I read a [couple](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/general-discussion-30/ea-origin-is-a-joke-518189/) [of](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/whats-deal-eas-origin-bad/) [reviews](https://www.google.com/search?q=ea+origin+review&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a), and am having second thoughts about downloading the client.

I have Steam, unfortunately this game is not available on Steam. May be if it is a small and thin client, yes... still I have to think about maintaining two stores. And if it is another steam, no way.

Answer (score 4):

If you buy games from Origin, you will need the Origin client to play those games.

How big, bloated or bulky you find it is obviously dependent on how good your computer is. If you're going to be play NFS 2012, a fairly recent game, it's not going to be noticeable idling in the background and it won't have a noticeable impact in-game.

IF you have Steam, it's not any more resource demanding than that.